# How can I calulate $\gcd(ab,c)$?

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

It is known that:

> If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(ab,c)=\gcd(a,c) \cdot \gcd(b,c)$.

Let $p$ be a prime number such that $p\mid a$. Then $v_p(b)=0$ (since $\gcd(a,b)=1$), $\min\{v_p(b),v_p(c)\}=0$ and : $$\min\{v_p(ab),v_p(c)\}=\min\{v_p(a),v_p(c)\}=\min\{v_p(a),v_p(c)\}+\min\{v_p(b),v_p(c)\}$$
The same happens with $p\mid b$, thus $$v_p(\gcd(ab,c))=v_p(\gcd(a,c)) + v_p(\gcd(b,c))=v_p(\gcd(a,c) \cdot \gcd(b,c))$$
$$\implies \gcd(ab,c)=\gcd(a,c) \cdot \gcd(b,c)$$

However, if $\gcd(a,b)>1$, how can I calculate $\gcd(ab,c)$ ?

Comment: @RushabhMehta : Then is it equal to $gcd(a,c) \cdot gcd(b,c)$?

Comment: $(a,c)(b,c) = (ab,cd)\, $ for $\,d=(a,b,c),\,$ so it holds more generally when $\,d = 1\ \ $

Comment: @RushabhMehta That's not correct.

Comment: "how can I calculate $\gcd(ab,c)$ with the values of $\gcd(a,c)$, $\gcd(b,c)$, $a,b$ and $c$?" Well, with $a,b$ and $c$, you just calculate $\gcd(ab,c)$. But if all you have is $\gcd(a,c)$ and $\gcd(b,c)$, you're out of luck. I'm sure you can construct an example where that's not enough information.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry. I have edited it. In fact I was looking for a formula of $gcd(ab,c)$

Comment: This past questions seems a bit related: [$(ab,c) = (a,c)(b,c)$ (weakest condition possible on $a,b,c$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1190196)

Comment: You can look at the exponents of $p$ in $a$, $b$ and $c$; from this viewpoint this is related to the question whether you can express $\min(\alpha+\beta,\gamma)$ just using $\min(\alpha,\gamma)$ and $\min(\beta,\gamma)$.

Comment: I've told you, Mathwriter, that you can construct an example where knowing $\gcd(a,c)$ and $\gcd(b,c)$ doesn't allow you to work out $\gcd(ab,c)$. Have you tried to do that?

Comment: Are you still here, Mathwriter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.